# Usb modem stick connecting to laptop.need to connect airlive wireless broadband router to share internet?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet

I connect the usb modem stick to my laptop and get the internet well. I have another laptop,tablet - sometimes I connect them by using mhotspot software running on my laptop.

Recently I got a broadband wireless router (airlive mimo g). I'd like to connect the router to my laptop and share the internet to other devices. Please provide me youtube,images for better understanding. Both laptops use windows 7 OS.

Answer (score 0):

I can not provide pictures atm, but the thing sounds pretty straight forward, especially when using Win7.
Connect both machines to the router and set the network type to "Home Network". Make sure the Machines see each other in the Network overview.

All you have to do now is to enable internet connection sharing in the settings of the internet-enabled connection on your main machine, then at least all windows machines on the router should be able to access the internet.

There is a step-by-step guide [here](http://mobileoffice.about.com/od/internet-sharing-tethering/ht/how-to-share-internet-connection-on-windows7.htm).